# How large can capacitive sensors be if made of tin foil?

Tags: sensor, capacitance, conductive

Based on a similar version of this: https://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-3D-Controller/

What are the limits to the size I can make this foil area?

And the larger I make it, what does the area need? More power? larger resistors?

How would you make a 70cm x 100cm foil sheet good enough enough to detect if you're touching an area of it?

I'm using an arduino nano, is this going to power in it to detect?

Comment: Your limiting factor is probably going to be noise. The larger the surface, the more likely it is to pick up noise.

Comment: You can't just use an Arduino to detect the touch of a capacitive sensor. What does "power in it to detect" mean? What does the rest of the electronics look like? Which "resistors" are you going to make larger?

Comment: At the moment, resisters are 220k and 10k for a small 10cm sheet. I'm trying to scale the project up, but I'm wondering where do I begin, if starting from scratch.

Comment: The limiting factor is thin you can make the insulating gap in [um]. Get a calculator

Comment: that is not tin foil .... it is aluminum foil ... tin is a different metal

Comment: Didn't really want to go this direction: "Tin foil, also spelled tinfoil, is a thin foil made of tin. Actual tin foil was superseded after World War II by cheaper and more durable[1] aluminium foil, which is still referred to as "tin foil" in many regions. 
" Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_foil

Answer (score 2):

The example you provided works by measuring capacitance between the foil plate and the "ground". "Ground" in this case is whatever the arduino GND net is tied to. It can be protective earth and therefore the size of electrical installation in the building, or it could be a battery pack and therefore quite small.

Hand or other conductive object in proximity changes the capacitance because it adds parallel capacitance to the foil-ground capacitance that is already there. The added capacitance is either

1. human-ground capacitance if hand is touching the plate, or
2. plate-human and human-ground capacitances in series if hand is in proximity, but not touching.

> What are the limits to the size I can make this foil area?
>
> How would you make a 70cm x 100cm foil sheet good enough enough to detect if you're touching an area of it?

Capacitance when there is no human in presence depends on the plate area. Capacitance with human depends on human's area. Measurements are going to be noisy so there will be a lower limit of value change that can be classified as presence that is proportional to plate area. For a very crude example, if you have a 2 square meter plate and a 1-year-old with ~0,5 square meter skin area touches it, you might have 25% increase in capacitance. Is that reliably detectable? It depends.

I did some experiments with 50x45 cm foil sheet. All measurements at 10 kHz. Me / child.

- Sheet capacitance to protective earth pin: 15 pF, 12k ESR / 15 pF, 12k ESR
- mouse mat and hand on it: 28 pF, 18 k ESR / n.a.
- 80 g paper sheet and hand: 36 pF, 20 k ESR / 21 pF, 15 k ESR
- same but with two hands: same / same
- hand directly on foil (no insulator): 38 pF, 20 k ESR. / 26 pF, 20 k ESR.

What about human-foil capacitance then? The one in series when there is an insulator?

- foil-paper-hand: 1150 pF, 3 k ESR / 490-700 pF, 7 k ESR.